# Can I have an Activity extend my Activity

Tags: android

I have created an `Activity` which allows a user to create a page. This PageActivity extends an `Activity`. Can I create a class called Update PageActivity that extends PageActivity?

Comment: Why not try and see? It's relatively trivial...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, as long as you did not declare `PageActivity` a `final` you may extend it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can.
Activity is just like any other Java Class.
Make sure you override the relevant Activity lifecycle functions - onCreate, onResume, etc...